# Purpose of re-usable Executor, ServiceExecutor, etc interfaces

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, concurrency, executorservice

I'm building a GUI'd application with javaFX that supports a long-running CPU intensive operation, something like Prime95 or Orthos.

One of the problems I've run into is trying to get counters to increment nicely. If you think about an `ElapsedTime` field with an incrementing counter with millisecond resolution, what I need is a job on the UI thread to call `elapsedTimeTextField.setText("00:00:00.001")` to happen 1ms before a corresponding call `elapsedTimeTextField.setText("00:00:00.002")`. I also need to let the UI thread do more important jobs between those two calls.

Structuring code to do this has been tedious, and has resulted in a number of our controller classes creating threads that simply loop on code similar to:

```
Thread worker = new Thread(this::doUpdates);
worker.start();

//...

private void doUpdates(){
  while(true){
    String computedTime = computeTimeToDisplay();
    runLaterOnUI(() -> textField.setText(computedTime));
    sleep(DUTY_CYCLE_DOWNTIME);
  }
}
```

While this *does the job*, its unfavorable because:

- It's difficult to unit test: from a testing environment you either have to modify this code to give some kind of signal when it completes its first pass, (typically a count-down-latch) or you have to do silly non-deterministic & arbitrary `sleep()`s
- It doesn't have any kind of backoff: if the UI thread is flooded with jobs this code is going to exacerbate the problem. Some kind of *requeueing* scheme, whereby the downtime takes into account the latency of the job and some kind of hard-coded sleep is preferable since it means that if the UI job is flooded we're not asking it to do work unduly.
- It doesn't have centralized exception handling short of the threads default handler. This means that if an exception is raised in the `computeTimeToDisplay()` method (or for that fact, in the `runLaterOnUI` call or the `sleep()` call) the text field will *no longer be updated*.

I have addressed each of these concerns reasonably well individually, but I don't have any obvious and reusable idiom for tackling these three problems.

I *suspect* that the `Future`, `Task`, `Executor`, `ServiceExecutor`, etc classes (the classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package that aren't a lock or a collection) can help me to this goal, but I'm not sure how to use them.

Can somebody suggest some documentation to read and some idioms to follow that will help me in pursuit of these goals? Is there an agreed on idiom --that doesn't involve anonymous classes and contains minimal boiler-plate-- for this kind of concurrent-job?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) with a core pool size of `1` and optionally with a thread priority of `Thread.NORM_PRIORITY + 1` (use a [ThreadFactoryBuilder](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release05/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html) to create a `ThreadFactory` with higher than standard priority) for the UI thread - this will let you schedule tasks such as the counter increment using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#scheduleAtFixedRate`.  Don't execute anything other than UI tasks on this executor - execute your CPU tasks on a separate `ThreadPoolExecutor` with standard priority; if you have e.g. 16 logical cores then create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 16 core threads to make full use of your computer when the UI thread is idle, and let the virtual machine take care of ensuring that the UI thread executes its jobs when it's supposed to.

Comment: That's a mouthful! Thanks very much for this!! So the reason you're suggesting the higher priority is so that the UI jobs will be scheduled ahead of the other more CPU intensive jobs, thus making the UI a little more responsive?

Comment: @Groostav That's correct, otherwise the UI updates may be laggy/choppy

Answer (score 1):

You question is multi-faceted and I am not going to pretend that I understand all of it.  This answer will address only one part of the question.

> It doesn't have any kind of backoff: if the UI thread is flooded with jobs this code is going to exacerbate the problem. Some kind of requeueing scheme, whereby the downtime takes into account the latency of the job and some kind of hard-coded sleep is preferable since it means that if the UI job is flooded we're not asking it to do work unduly.

The in-built java.util.concurrent classes such as [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), Service and ScheduledService include facilities to send message updates from a non-UI thread to a UI thread in way that does not flood the UI thread.  You could use those classes directly (which would seem advisable, though perhaps that perception is naive of me as I don't fully understand your requirements).  Or you can implement a similar custom facility in your code if you aren't using java.util.concurrent directly.

Here is the relevant code from the Task implementation:

```
/**
 * Used to send message updates in a thread-safe manner from the subclass
 * to the FX application thread. AtomicReference is used so as to coalesce
 * updates such that we don't flood the event queue.
 */
private AtomicReference<String> messageUpdate = new AtomicReference<>();

private final StringProperty message = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "message", "");

/**
 * Updates the <code>message</code> property. Calls to updateMessage
 * are coalesced and run later on the FX application thread, so calls
 * to updateMessage, even from the FX Application thread, may not
 * necessarily result in immediate updates to this property, and
 * intermediate message values may be coalesced to save on event
 * notifications.
 * <p>
 *     <em>This method is safe to be called from any thread.</em>
 * </p>
 *
 * @param message the new message
 */
protected void updateMessage(String message) {
    if (isFxApplicationThread()) {
        this.message.set(message);
    } else {
        // As with the workDone, it might be that the background thread
        // will update this message quite frequently, and we need
        // to throttle the updates so as not to completely clobber
        // the event dispatching system.
        if (messageUpdate.getAndSet(message) == null) {
            runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    final String message = messageUpdate.getAndSet(null);
                    Task.this.message.set(message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The code works by ensuring that a `runLater` call is only made if the UI has processed (i.e. rendered) the last update.

Internally the JavaFX 8 system runs on a pulse system.  Unless there is an unusually long time consuming operation on the UI thread or general system slowdown, each pulse will usually occur 60 times a second, or approximately every 16-17 milliseconds.

You mention the following:

> what I need is a job on the UI thread to call elapsedTimeTextField.setText("00:00:00.001") to happen 1ms before a corresponding call elapsedTimeTextField.setText("00:00:00.002").

However, you can see from the JavaFX architecture description that updating the text more than 60 times a second is pointless as the additional updates will never be rendered.  The sample code above from Task, takes care of this by ensuring that a UI update request is only ever issued at a time that the UI update thread can actually reflect the new value in the UI.

*Some General Advice*

This is just advice, it does not directly solve your problem, take it for what you will, some of it might not even be particularly relevant to your situation or problem.

1. Make clear the problem you are trying to solve in your questions.  That is sometimes more important than a description of the symptoms you are experiencing and trying to resolve.  It also helps prevent [XY questions](http://xyproblem.info).
2. Be clear from the start on what you are actually doing to solve the problem.  An [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can sometimes help here.
3. For example, your initial problem statement does not state that you may have 10,000 controllers or provide code for what you term to be a controller.  There is not much information on the expected length of time for tasks, what the UI display representing task progress and result is, why millisecond accuracy level might be important to display, if task results need to coalesced, if the tasks can be split and run concurrently, how many threads you are using, etc.
4. Don't try to develop your own higher level concurrency tools from primitives like ConcurrentLinkedQueue.
5. For your backend segmented work jobs, use [high level concurrency utilities from Java SE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html), such as [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html), [ForkJoin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) and [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html).
6. Orchestrate and synchronize the output of backend jobs with your UI using [JavaFX concurrency utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) such as [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).
7. Know that the high level concurrency utilities and JavaFX concurrency tools can be used in unison, like in [this example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5072743). I.e., the choice of concurrency tools doesn't need to be an either/or situation.
8. Extensive use of [immutable objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) can be a lifesaver in concurrent development.
9. If you will be doing a lot of concurrent development, take time for detailed study of high quality resources on concurrent programming such as [Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).
10. Concurrency in general is often simply hard to get right.

Comment: Regarding #1: consider the case where 10 000 controllers each want an elapsed time text-field, and each use a `DUTY_CYCLE_DOWNTIME` value of 1ms. This isn't scalable for many reasons, but one of them is because we're going to enqueue 10,000 jobs every 1 ms, and because immediately after a job is enqueued we're going to begin the next wait for 1ms, without taking into account the actual time it took for that job to get executed, the job queue is going to be flooded. [This is a gist](https://gist.github.com/Groostav/cc3e9786bde5adec3b3f) that solves the problem, but isn't very re-usable.

Comment: Regarding #2: That's really obvious and I should've known that, but regardless, if their goal is to have a setText call go off every 1ms --which will make sense to any junior dev reading this-- I would like some intuitive way for them to schedule this job.